# Can a Man-in-the-Middle-Attack be achieved by adding a cloudfront domain to a domain not owned by me?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-cloudfront

Let's say I have a REST API running on ECS behind an Application Load Balancer(ALB) on AWS. The ALB is fronted by a cloudfront domain, called abcd.cloudfront.net. As one would expect, there's a CNAME record setup on the DNS provider called app.mysite.com pointing to the cloudfront domain with a valid SSL cert from ACM. The ALB has a rule to only allow requests that have the header HOST:app.mysite.com. This create a pretty standard API flow on AWS.

What would happen if someone, with no access to my AWS account, sets up a new cloudfront domain, abcd2.cloudfront.net with the domain app.fake-mysite.com and valid ACM cert *(for app.fake-mysite.com), and adds a behavior to point to app.mysite.com. Can this external entity use it's own ACM cert to cause a Man in the Middle Attack?

The request flow would look like this:

app.fake-mysite.com -> abcd2.cloudfront.net -> app.mysite.com -> abcd.cloudfront.net -> my-alb.domain -> 10.0.0.100:8080 (REST API)

Would it be possible for the external entity to intercept the request at the first hop and capture the encrypted data? If so, how can this be prevented?

*updated for clarity.

Comment: How would they get a valid ACM cert?

Comment: The app.fake-mysite.com domain is owned by this external entity, so it should not be a problem to issue a valid ACM cert. I tried this "cloudfront hopping" with another domain that I own, and it seems to work.

Comment: it's not "man-in-the-middle" attack, as the certificate belongs to the fake app.. just using your services as a backend. if the user is using your app directly and the set if root certificates is not compromised, it's not mitm

Comment: Okay, so it's not a MITM in the scenario you're proposing, where the external entity is unable to override the cert on my domain. But my question is what happens if the user goes through the external entities' domain (app.fake-mysite.com)?

Comment: Better to be asked on [information security](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Question is not really about programming; Might be better suited for either networking (https://serverfault.com/) or info sec (https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @kelalaka that was a great suggestion! I followed up on information security stackexchange and got my answer.

Comment: @acorbel Please take a look at the comments under the accepted answer on security stackexchange, the custom headers can be bypassed.

Comment: Ah, this must be deleted, then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered over at information security. The answer is that this a valid phishing attack.

Link to accepted answer:
https://security.stackexchange.com/a/249166/256945

Answer (score 1):

"Would it be possible for the external entity to intercept the request at the first hop and capture the encrypted data?"

No, the external entity can not intercept as the browser will get a 301 Permanent Redirect.

Browser -> app.fake-mysite.com -> abcd2.cloudfront.net -> 301 to browser with redirect url as app.mysite.com

[image]

Browser -> app.mysite.com -> abcd.cloudfront.net -> my-alb.domain -> 10.0.0.100:8080 (REST API)

[image]

So, after the redirect the communication is directly between the browser and actual website.

Comment: Would it be a 301? As far as the REST API is concerned, the request would be coming from app.mysite.com. From what I understand, when adding custom origins to cloudfront distribution, cloudfront takes your origin request payload and makes a new request to the origin. Wouldn't that mean that the REST API would be unaware of the fact that the request originated at app.fake-mysite.com?

Comment: I have added screenshots for more clarity. It will be a 301 if you access  app.fake-mysite.com from browser. After 301, user's browser will then be talking to app.mysite.com and not fake.com. Check the network tab in screenshot2.

Comment: I have one request. Can you please setup a new domain name for your cloudfront distribution? This, along with a valid ACM cert will stop the 301 redirects. If you look at my original question, it includes app.fake-mysite.com. I did this experiment on some of my own domains, and adding the alternate CNAME stops the 301 redirects.

Comment: pls share your screenshot showing the network tab for the REST call... Even if you invoke REST call from app.fake on your API on backend, the response will not be readable on the browser due to CORS policies...

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot expose the application where I did this test. I got an answer to this question on information security: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/249166/256945 . Thanks again for looking into it!

Comment: Just to clarify in a phishing attack a fake UI is provided but in your case your are redirecting to UI of genuine domain so browser will talk to genuine domain and phishing won’t happen. Hypothetically, even if you consider that phishing happens then as well genuine domain will reject the request because genuine domain would have measures like captcha which will identify phishing requests and not give an access token if user is tricked to provide username and password. So, assuming a properly secure backend exists, creating such fake sites won’t be able to break security.

Comment: But off-course if username and password is compromised then hacker can always break in unless you have MFA enabled.

Comment: I have to disagree about the redirect. Since the fake cloudfront dist makes a genuine request to the true (app.mysite.com) domain, there will be no redirects. The wrapper cloudfront dist along with a valid domain name acts a proxy to the real domain, so the backend is unaware of this wrapper existing. To the backend server, it will look like the request is coming from app.mysite.com, as the request does get routed through that domain. As mentioned in the comments on infromation security, a good check is using javascript to ensure the `location.href` is pointing to the correct domain.